# Select minute from CURTIME() in a sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a column with `CURTIME()` value. 
I want a query that selects the minute from the column with `CURTIME()` and copy the minute to another column.

Comment: Please show your latest failed attempt. It's usually easier to correct someone's non-working query than to make a new query from scratch.

Comment: Have you tried the `minute()` function?  `minute(curtime())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`minute`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_minute) function.

If you're just querying it:

```
SELECT MINUTE(my_time_column) FROM mytable
```

To save this value to another column:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET    my_minute_column = MINUTE(my_time_column);
```